# How to use singularity and conda wrappers in Snakemake

Tags: python, conda, snakemake, singularity-container

**TLDR** I'm getting the following error:

> The 'conda' command is not available inside your singularity container image. Snakemake mounts your conda installation into singularity. Sometimes, this can fail because of shell restrictions. It has been tested to work with docker://ubuntu, but it e.g. fails with docker://bash

I had created a `Snakemake` workflow and converted the `shell:`  commands to rule-based package management via [Snakemake `wrappers:`](https://snakemake-wrappers.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) .

However, I ran into issues running this on HPC and one of the HPC support staff strongly recommended against using `conda` on any HPC system as:

> "if the builder [of wrapper] is not *super* careful, dynamic libraries present in the conda environment that relies on the host libs (there are always a couple present because builder are most of the time carefree) will break. I think that relying on `Singularity` for your pipeline would make for a more robust system." - *Anon*

I did some reading over the weekend and [according to this document, it's possible to combine containers with conda-based package management](https://reproducibility.sschmeier.com/container/index.html); by defining a global `conda` docker container and per-rule `yaml` files.

> *Note:* In contrast to the example in the link above (*Figure 5.4*), which uses a predefined `yaml` and `shell:`  command, here I've use
> conda wrappers which download these `yaml` files into the
> `Singularity` container (if I'm thinking correctly) so I *thought* should function the same - see the *Note:* at the end though...

### `Snakefile`, `config.yaml` and `samples.txt`

#### `Snakefile`

```
# Directories------------------------------------------------------------------
configfile: "config.yaml"

# Setting the names of all directories
dir_list = ["REF_DIR", "LOG_DIR", "BENCHMARK_DIR", "QC_DIR", "TRIM_DIR", "ALIGN_DIR", "MARKDUP_DIR", "CALLING_DIR", "ANNOT_DIR"]
dir_names = ["refs", "logs", "benchmarks", "qc", "trimming", "alignment", "mark_duplicates", "variant_calling", "annotation"]
dirs_dict = dict(zip(dir_list, dir_names))

import os
import pandas as pd
# getting the samples information (names, path to r1 & r2) from samples.txt
samples_information = pd.read_csv("samples.txt", sep='\t', index_col=False)
# get a list of the sample names
sample_names = list(samples_information['sample'])
sample_locations = list(samples_information['location'])
samples_dict = dict(zip(sample_names, sample_locations))
# get number of samples
len_samples = len(sample_names)


# Singularity with conda wrappers

singularity: "docker://continuumio/miniconda3:4.5.11"

# Rules -----------------------------------------------------------------------

rule all:
    input:
        "resources/vep/plugins",
        "resources/vep/cache"

rule download_vep_plugins:
    output:
        directory("resources/vep/plugins")
    params:
        release=100
    resources:
        mem=1000,
        time=30
    wrapper:
        "0.66.0/bio/vep/plugins"

rule get_vep_cache:
    output:
        directory("resources/vep/cache")
    params:
        species="caenorhabditis_elegans",
        build="WBcel235",
        release="100"
    resources:
        mem=1000,
        time=30
    log:
        "logs/vep/cache.log"
    cache: True  # save space and time with between workflow caching (see docs)
    wrapper:
        "0.66.0/bio/vep/cache"
```

#### `config.yaml`

```
# Files
REF_GENOME: "c_elegans.PRJNA13758.WS265.genomic.fa"
GENOME_ANNOTATION: "c_elegans.PRJNA13758.WS265.annotations.gff3"

# Tools
QC_TOOL: "fastQC"
TRIM_TOOL: "trimmomatic"
ALIGN_TOOL: "bwa"
MARKDUP_TOOL: "picard"
CALLING_TOOL: "varscan"
ANNOT_TOOL: "vep"
```

#### `samples.txt`

```
sample  location
MTG324  /home/moldach/wrappers/SUBSET/MTG324_SUBSET
```

### Submission

```
snakemake --profile slurm --use-singularity --use-conda --jobs 2
```

### Logs

```
Workflow defines that rule get_vep_cache is eligible for caching between workflows (use the --cache argument to enable this).
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cores: 1 (use --cores to define parallelism)
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job counts:
    count   jobs
        1   get_vep_cache
        1

[Mon Sep 21 15:35:50 2020]
rule get_vep_cache:
    output: resources/vep/cache
    log: logs/vep/cache.log
    jobid: 0
    resources: mem=1000, time=30

Activating singularity image /home/moldach/wrappers/SUBSET/VEP/.snakemake/singularity/d7617773b315c3abcb29e0484085ed06.simg
Activating conda environment: /home/moldach/wrappers/SUBSET/VEP/.snakemake/conda/774ea575
[Mon Sep 21 15:36:38 2020]
Finished job 0.
1 of 1 steps (100%) done
```

> *Note:* Leaving `--use-conda` out of the submission of the workflow will cause an error for `get_vep_cache:` - `/bin/bash: vep_install: command not found`

```
Workflow defines that rule get_vep_cache is eligible for caching between workflows (use the --cache argument to enable this).
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cores: 1 (use --cores to define parallelism)
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job counts:
    count   jobs
        1   download_vep_plugins
        1

[Mon Sep 21 15:35:50 2020]
rule download_vep_plugins:
    output: resources/vep/plugins
    jobid: 0
    resources: mem=1000, time=30

Activating singularity image /home/moldach/wrappers/SUBSET/VEP/.snakemake/singularity/d7617773b315c3abcb29e0484085ed06.simg
Activating conda environment: /home/moldach/wrappers/SUBSET/VEP/.snakemake/conda/9f602d9a
[Mon Sep 21 15:35:56 2020]
Finished job 0.
1 of 1 steps (100%) done
```

The problem occurs when adding the third rule, `fastq`:

### Updated `Snakefile`

```
# Directories------------------------------------------------------------------
configfile: "config.yaml"

# Setting the names of all directories
dir_list = ["REF_DIR", "LOG_DIR", "BENCHMARK_DIR", "QC_DIR", "TRIM_DIR", "ALIGN_DIR", "MARKDUP_DIR", "CALLING_DIR", "ANNOT_DIR"]
dir_names = ["refs", "logs", "benchmarks", "qc", "trimming", "alignment", "mark_duplicates", "variant_calling", "annotation"]
dirs_dict = dict(zip(dir_list, dir_names))

import os
import pandas as pd
# getting the samples information (names, path to r1 & r2) from samples.txt
samples_information = pd.read_csv("samples.txt", sep='\t', index_col=False)
# get a list of the sample names
sample_names = list(samples_information['sample'])
sample_locations = list(samples_information['location'])
samples_dict = dict(zip(sample_names, sample_locations))
# get number of samples
len_samples = len(sample_names)


# Singularity with conda wrappers

singularity: "docker://continuumio/miniconda3:4.5.11"

# Rules -----------------------------------------------------------------------

rule all:
    input:
        "resources/vep/plugins",
        "resources/vep/cache",
        expand('{QC_DIR}/{QC_TOOL}/before_trim/{sample}_{pair}_fastqc.{ext}', QC_DIR=dirs_dict["QC_DIR"], QC_TOOL=config["QC_TOOL"], sample=sample_names, pair=['R1', 'R2'], ext=['html', 'zip'])

rule download_vep_plugins:
    output:
        directory("resources/vep/plugins")
    params:
        release=100
    resources:
        mem=1000,
        time=30
    wrapper:
        "0.66.0/bio/vep/plugins"

rule get_vep_cache:
    output:
        directory("resources/vep/cache")
    params:
        species="caenorhabditis_elegans",
        build="WBcel235",
        release="100"
    resources:
        mem=1000,
        time=30
    log:
        "logs/vep/cache.log"
    cache: True  # save space and time with between workflow caching (see docs)
    wrapper:
        "0.66.0/bio/vep/cache"

def getHome(sample):
  return(list(os.path.join(samples_dict[sample],"{0}_{1}.fastq.gz".format(sample,pair)) for pair in ['R1','R2']))

rule qc_before_trim_r1:
    input:
        r1=lambda wildcards: getHome(wildcards.sample)[0]
    output:
        html=os.path.join(dirs_dict["QC_DIR"],config["QC_TOOL"],"before_trim","{sample}_R1_fastqc.html"),
        zip=os.path.join(dirs_dict["QC_DIR"],config["QC_TOOL"],"before_trim","{sample}_R1_fastqc.zip"),
    params:
         dir=os.path.join(dirs_dict["QC_DIR"],config["QC_TOOL"],"before_trim")
    log:
        os.path.join(dirs_dict["LOG_DIR"],config["QC_TOOL"],"{sample}_R1.log")
    resources:
        mem=1000,
        time=30
    singularity:
        "https://depot.galaxyproject.org/singularity/fastqc:0.11.9--0"
    threads: 1
    message: """--- Quality check of raw data with FastQC before trimming."""
    wrapper:
         "0.66.0/bio/fastqc"

rule qc_before_trim_r2:
    input:
        r1=lambda wildcards: getHome(wildcards.sample)[1]
    output:
        html=os.path.join(dirs_dict["QC_DIR"],config["QC_TOOL"],"before_trim","{sample}_R2_fastqc.html"),
        zip=os.path.join(dirs_dict["QC_DIR"],config["QC_TOOL"],"before_trim","{sample}_R2_fastqc.zip"),
    params:
         dir=os.path.join(dirs_dict["QC_DIR"],config["QC_TOOL"],"before_trim")
    log:
        os.path.join(dirs_dict["LOG_DIR"],config["QC_TOOL"],"{sample}_R2.log")
    resources:
        mem=1000,
        time=30
    singularity:
        "https://depot.galaxyproject.org/singularity/fastqc:0.11.9--0"
    threads: 1
    message: """--- Quality check of raw data with FastQC before trimming."""
    wrapper:
        "0.66.0/bio/fastqc"
```

### Error reported in `nohup.out`

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Pulling singularity image https://depot.galaxyproject.org/singularity/fastqc:0.11.9--0.
CreateCondaEnvironmentException:
The 'conda' command is not available inside your singularity container image. Snakemake mounts your conda installation into singularity. Sometimes, this can fail because of shell restrictions. It has been tested to work with docker://ubuntu, but it e.g. fails with docker://bash 
  File "/home/moldach/anaconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/conda.py", line 247, in create
  File "/home/moldach/anaconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/conda.py", line 381, in __new__
  File "/home/moldach/anaconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/conda.py", line 394, in __init__
  File "/home/moldach/anaconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/conda.py", line 417, in _check
```

#### using `shell:`  instead of `wrapper:`

I changed the wrapper back into the shell command:

and this is the error I get when submitting with ``:

```
orkflow defines that rule get_vep_cache is eligible for caching between workflows (use the --cache argument to enable this).
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cores: 1 (use --cores to define parallelism)
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job counts:
    count   jobs
        1   qc_before_trim_r2
        1

[Mon Sep 21 16:32:54 2020]
Job 0: --- Quality check of raw data with FastQC before trimming.

Activating singularity image /home/moldach/wrappers/SUBSET/VEP/.snakemake/singularity/6740cb07e67eae01644839c9767bdca5.simg
^[[33mWARNING:^[[0m Skipping mount /var/singularity/mnt/session/etc/resolv.conf [files]: /etc/resolv.conf doesn't exist in container
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "en_CA.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Skipping '/home/moldach/wrappers/SUBSET/MTG324_SUBSET/MTG324_R2.fastq.gz' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
Waiting at most 60 seconds for missing files.
MissingOutputException in line 84 of /home/moldach/wrappers/SUBSET/VEP/Snakefile:
Job completed successfully, but some output files are missing. Missing files after 60 seconds:
qc/fastQC/before_trim/MTG324_R2_fastqc.html
qc/fastQC/before_trim/MTG324_R2_fastqc.zip
This might be due to filesystem latency. If that is the case, consider to increase the wait time with --latency-wait.
  File "/home/moldach/anaconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 544, in handle_job_success
  File "/home/moldach/anaconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 231, in handle_job_success
Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

The error `Skipping '/home/moldach/wrappers/SUBSET/MTG324_SUBSET/MTG324_R2.fastq.gz' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read` is misleading because the file is does exist...

### **Update 2**

Following the advice [Manavalan Gajapathy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3998252/manavalan-gajapathy) I've eliminated defining singularity at two different levels (global + per-rule).

Now I'm using a singularity container at only the global level and using wrappers via `--use-conda` which creates the conda environment inside of the container:

```
# Directories------------------------------------------------------------------
configfile: "config.yaml"

# Setting the names of all directories
dir_list = ["REF_DIR", "LOG_DIR", "BENCHMARK_DIR", "QC_DIR", "TRIM_DIR", "ALIGN_DIR", "MARKDUP_DIR", "CALLING_DIR", "ANNOT_DIR"]
dir_names = ["refs", "logs", "benchmarks", "qc", "trimming", "alignment", "mark_duplicates", "variant_calling", "annotation"]
dirs_dict = dict(zip(dir_list, dir_names))

import os
import pandas as pd
# getting the samples information (names, path to r1 & r2) from samples.txt
samples_information = pd.read_csv("samples.txt", sep='\t', index_col=False)
# get a list of the sample names
sample_names = list(samples_information['sample'])
sample_locations = list(samples_information['location'])
samples_dict = dict(zip(sample_names, sample_locations))
# get number of samples
len_samples = len(sample_names)


# Singularity with conda wrappers

singularity: "docker://continuumio/miniconda3:4.5.11"

# Rules -----------------------------------------------------------------------

rule all:
    input:
    "resources/vep/plugins",
        "resources/vep/cache",
        expand('{QC_DIR}/{QC_TOOL}/before_trim/{sample}_{pair}_fastqc.{ext}', QC_DIR=dirs_dict["QC_DIR"], QC_TOOL=config["QC_TOOL"], sample=sample_names, pair=['R1', 'R2'], ext=['html', 'zip'])

rule download_vep_plugins:
    output:
    directory("resources/vep/plugins")
    params:
    release=100
    resources:
    mem=1000,
        time=30
    wrapper:
    "0.66.0/bio/vep/plugins"

rule get_vep_cache:
    output:
    directory("resources/vep/cache")
    params:
    species="caenorhabditis_elegans",
        build="WBcel235",
        release="100"
    resources:
    mem=1000,
        time=30
    log:
        "logs/vep/cache.log"
    cache: True  # save space and time with between workflow caching (see docs)
    wrapper:
    "0.66.0/bio/vep/cache"

def getHome(sample):
  return(list(os.path.join(samples_dict[sample],"{0}_{1}.fastq.gz".format(sample,pair)) for pair in ['R1','R2']))

rule qc_before_trim_r1:
    input:
    r1=lambda wildcards: getHome(wildcards.sample)[0]
    output:
    html=os.path.join(dirs_dict["QC_DIR"],config["QC_TOOL"],"before_trim","{sample}_R1_fastqc.html"),
        zip=os.path.join(dirs_dict["QC_DIR"],config["QC_TOOL"],"before_trim","{sample}_R1_fastqc.zip"),
    params:
    dir=os.path.join(dirs_dict["QC_DIR"],config["QC_TOOL"],"before_trim")
    log:
        os.path.join(dirs_dict["LOG_DIR"],config["QC_TOOL"],"{sample}_R1.log")
    resources:
    mem=1000,
    threads: 1
    message: """--- Quality check of raw data with FastQC before trimming."""
    wrapper:
    "0.66.0/bio/fastqc"

rule qc_before_trim_r2:
    input:
    r1=lambda wildcards: getHome(wildcards.sample)[1]
    output:
    html=os.path.join(dirs_dict["QC_DIR"],config["QC_TOOL"],"before_trim","{sample}_R2_fastqc.html"),
        zip=os.path.join(dirs_dict["QC_DIR"],config["QC_TOOL"],"before_trim","{sample}_R2_fastqc.zip"),
    params:
    dir=os.path.join(dirs_dict["QC_DIR"],config["QC_TOOL"],"before_trim")
    log:
        os.path.join(dirs_dict["LOG_DIR"],config["QC_TOOL"],"{sample}_R2.log")
    resources:
    mem=1000,
        time=30
    threads: 1
    message: """--- Quality check of raw data with FastQC before trimming."""
    wrapper:
    "0.66.0/bio/fastqc"
```

and submit via:

However, I'm still getting an error:

```
Workflow defines that rule get_vep_cache is eligible for caching between workflows (use the --cache argument to enable this).
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cores: 1 (use --cores to define parallelism)
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job counts:
    count   jobs
        1   qc_before_trim_r2
        1

[Tue Sep 22 12:44:03 2020]
Job 0: --- Quality check of raw data with FastQC before trimming.

Activating singularity image /home/moldach/wrappers/SUBSET/OMG/.snakemake/singularity/d7617773b315c3abcb29e0484085ed06.simg
Activating conda environment: /home/moldach/wrappers/SUBSET/OMG/.snakemake/conda/c591f288
Skipping '/work/mtgraovac_lab/MATTS_SCRATCH/rep1_R2.fastq.gz' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
Skipping ' 2> logs/fastQC/rep1_R2.log' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
Failed to process qc/fastQC/before_trim
java.io.FileNotFoundException: qc/fastQC/before_trim (Is a directory)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
        at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Sequence.FastQFile.<init>(FastQFile.java:73)
        at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Sequence.SequenceFactory.getSequenceFile(SequenceFactory.java:106)
        at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Sequence.SequenceFactory.getSequenceFile(SequenceFactory.java:62)
        at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Analysis.OfflineRunner.processFile(OfflineRunner.java:159)
        at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Analysis.OfflineRunner.<init>(OfflineRunner.java:121)
        at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.FastQCApplication.main(FastQCApplication.java:316)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/moldach/wrappers/SUBSET/OMG/.snakemake/scripts/tmpiwwprg5m.wrapper.py", line 35, in <module>
    shell(
  File "/mnt/snakemake/snakemake/shell.py", line 205, in __new__
    raise sp.CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'set -euo pipefail;  fastqc qc/fastQC/before_trim --quiet -t 1 --outdir /tmp/tmps93snag8 /work/mtgraovac_lab/MATTS_SCRATCH/rep1_R2.fastq.gz ' 2> logs/fastQC/rep1_R$
[Tue Sep 22 12:44:16 2020]
Error in rule qc_before_trim_r2:
    jobid: 0
    output: qc/fastQC/before_trim/rep1_R2_fastqc.html, qc/fastQC/before_trim/rep1_R2_fastqc.zip
    log: logs/fastQC/rep1_R2.log (check log file(s) for error message)
    conda-env: /home/moldach/wrappers/SUBSET/OMG/.snakemake/conda/c591f288

RuleException:
CalledProcessError in line 97 of /home/moldach/wrappers/SUBSET/OMG/Snakefile:
Command ' singularity exec --home /home/moldach/wrappers/SUBSET/OMG  --bind /home/moldach/anaconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.7/site-packages:/mnt/snakemake /home/moldach/wrappers/SUBSET/OMG/.snakemake$
  File "/home/moldach/anaconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 2189, in run_wrapper
  File "/home/moldach/wrappers/SUBSET/OMG/Snakefile", line 97, in __rule_qc_before_trim_r2
  File "/home/moldach/anaconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 529, in _callback
  File "/home/moldach/anaconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
  File "/home/moldach/anaconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 515, in cached_or_run
  File "/home/moldach/anaconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 2201, in run_wrapper
Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

#### Reproducibility

To replicate this you can download this small dataset:

```
git clone https://github.com/CRG-CNAG/CalliNGS-NF.git
cp CalliNGS-NF/data/reads/rep1_*.fq.gz .
mv rep1_1.fq.gz rep1_R1.fastq.gz 
mv rep1_2.fq.gz rep1_R2.fastq.gz
```

#### **UPDATE 3: Bind Mounts**

According to the link shared on [mounting](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.6/user-guide/quick_start.html#working-with-files):

> "By default Singularity bind mounts `/home/$USER`, `/tmp`, and `$PWD` into your container at runtime."

Thus, for simplicity (and also because I got errors using `--singularity-args`), I've moved the required files into `/home/$USER` and tried to run from there.

```
(snakemake) [~]$ pwd
/home/moldach


(snakemake) [~]$ ll
total 3656
drwx------ 26 moldach moldach    4096 Aug 27 17:36 anaconda3
drwx------  2 moldach moldach    4096 Sep 22 10:11 bin
-rw-------  1 moldach moldach     265 Sep 22 14:29 config.yaml
-rw-------  1 moldach moldach 1817903 Sep 22 14:29 rep1_R1.fastq.gz
-rw-------  1 moldach moldach 1870497 Sep 22 14:29 rep1_R2.fastq.gz
-rw-------  1 moldach moldach      55 Sep 22 14:29 samples.txt
-rw-------  1 moldach moldach    3420 Sep 22 14:29 Snakefile
```

and ran with `bash -c "nohup snakemake --profile slurm --use-singularity --use-conda --jobs 4 &"`

However, I still get this odd error:

```
Activating conda environment: /home/moldach/.snakemake/conda/fdae4f0d
Skipping ' 2> logs/fastQC/rep1_R2.log' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
Failed to process qc/fastQC/before_trim
java.io.FileNotFoundException: qc/fastQC/before_trim (Is a directory)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
        at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Sequence.FastQFile.<init>(FastQFile.java:73)
        at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Sequence.SequenceFactory.getSequenceFile(SequenceFactory.java:106)
        at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Sequence.SequenceFactory.getSequenceFile(SequenceFactory.java:62)
        at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Analysis.OfflineRunner.processFile(OfflineRunner.java:159)
        at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Analysis.OfflineRunner.<init>(OfflineRunner.java:121)
        at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.FastQCApplication.main(FastQCApplication.java:316)
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Why does it think it's being given a directory?

> *Note:* If you submit *only* with `--use-conda`, *e.g.* `bash -c "nohup snakemake --profile slurm --use-conda --jobs 4 &"` there is no error from the `fastqc` rules.  However, the `--use-conda` param alone is *not %100 reproducible*, case-in-point **doesn't work on another HPC I tested it on**

[The full log in `nohup.out` when using `--printshellcmds` can be found at this gist](https://gist.github.com/moldach/9d202c8303947b1481e0742231dfcaaf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:**

fastqc singularity container used in qc rule likely doesn't have `conda` available in it, and this doesn't satisfy what snakemake's`--use-conda` expects.

**Explanation:**

You have singularity containers defined at two different levels - 1. global level that will be used for all rules, unless they are overridden at rule level; 2. per-rule level that will be used at the rule level.

```py
# global singularity container to use
singularity: "docker://continuumio/miniconda3:4.5.11"

# singularity container defined at rule level
rule qc_before_trim_r1:
    ....
    ....
    singularity:
        "https://depot.galaxyproject.org/singularity/fastqc:0.11.9--0"
```

When you use `--use-singularity` and `--use-conda` together, jobs will be run in conda environment inside the singularity container. So `conda` command needs to be available inside the singularity container for this to be possible. While this requirement is clearly satisfied for your global-level container, I am quite certain (haven't tested though) this is not the case for your `fastqc` container.

The way snakemake works if `--use-conda` flag is supplied, it will create conda environment locally or inside the container depending on the supply of `--use-singularity` flag. Since you are using snakemake-wrapper for qc rule and it comes with conda env recipe pre-defined, the easiest solution here is to just use the globally defined miniconda container for all rules. That is, there is no need to use fastqc specific container for qc rule.

If you really want to use the fastqc container, then you shouldn't be using `--use-conda` flag, but of course this will mean that all necessary tools are available from the container(s) defined globally or per rule.

Comment: Thanks for your response Manavalan,
I've tried it out but I still get an error.
I've now updated the question to include a small sample data set for reproducibilty

Comment: It appears files/directories are not [mounted](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.6/user-guide/quick_start.html#working-with-files) in order to be available inside singularity container. Such bind paths can be supplied to snakemake using [`--singularity-args`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#SINGULARITY). I'll post if I find a tutorial demonstrating this.

Comment: Had trouble with `--singularity-args` as well as the default directory (see: _update #3 above_)

Comment: I bit the bullet and ran your code; Turns out snakemake wrapper version for `fastqc` that you are using has a bug, which I will report soon and link here. You will need to do two things to make the workflow run: 1. Use fastqc wrapper version `0.62.0` instead of `0.66.0`; 2. Comment out `params` for qc rules. It should work now. `params` is specifying a directory but `fastqc` doesn't know what to do with it, which is why we commented it out.

Comment: Tip: You might want to try [flag `--printshellcmds`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#OUTPUT), which will show you the exact command (`fastqc` command here) that gets executed by snakemake.

Comment: Filed the [issue](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake-wrappers/issues/191) describing the problem.

Comment: Thank you fora dding an issue about the log for the wrapper. I meant to do that but I've filed a few other issues in the past month already.
I'm attaching the full log from `--printshellcmds` above. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I see error related to different rule in your updated error logs. Does this mean qc rules run fine using my suggested inputs? Also, I would suggest creating a minimal example and making sure it works with conda and singularity. It would help keeping this Q&A focused.

Comment: I've placed all the files into a git repo to simplify things. All that's required is to update the PATH in `samples.txt` to match your PATH: https://github.com/moldach/snakemake-singularity/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221962/discussion-between-manavalan-gajapathy-and-matthew-j-oldach).